# Is there a way to prepend file names based on respective folders?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have a few folders with word document files of my notes. I want to run a simple bash loop help organise the names.

The current layout is:
data

```
 folder1
   1.jpg
   2.jpg
 folder2
   1.jpg
```

.. etc

I want to rename all the jpg files so that it is `folderX_1.jpg`.

Can it be done only writing one loop?

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

origdir=$(pwd)

rm -fr source
mkdir source
cd source
mkdir folder1
touch folder1/1.jpg
touch folder1/2.jpg
mkdir folder2
touch folder2/1.jpg
cd ..

find source -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' onefile
do
    dirname=$(dirname "$onefile" | tr '/' '-')
    filename=$(basename "$onefile")
    cp "$onefile" "$origdir"/"$dirname"-"$filename"
done
```

- The first part is just to create a test directory / file structure, remove or modify as required.
- The `find ... | while ...` loops through each file in the directory / sub-directory structure.
- for each file, extract the directory name (replacing '/' by '-' for sub-directories), extract the filename and copy the file.
- if you want to move instead of copy, change `cp` by `mv`